# Insert selective columns into pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema :

col1 as col1,
col 2,
col 3,
.
.
col n

I have another dataframe with the following schema

col1 as diffName,
col n+1,
col n+2
.
.
.

how can i append values in col 1 of dataframe and the rest of the columns as null values?

**i have tried using union as well as merge but to no avail**

Comment: Can you provide an example of each dataframe, and what you would like the result to look like?

Comment: simply put - I would like to append selective columns from one dataframe into another dataframe when both have different schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually make the columns of both dataframes match, then union them. For example, with these dataframes:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2),
    (3, 4)
], ['a', 'b'])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (5, 6, 7),
    (8, 9, 10)
], ['a2', 'c', 'd'])

df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed('a2', 'a')
```

The first step would be to make sure the column that is common to both dataframes has the same name:

```py
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed('a2', 'a')
```

Then you can make the columns match:

```py
for c in df2.columns:
    if c not in df1.columns:
        df1 = df1.withColumn(c, lit(None))

for c in df1.columns:
    if c not in df2.columns:
        df2 = df2.withColumn(c, lit(None))
```

Finally, you can take the union. I find `unionByName` to be safer:

```py
df_all = df1.unionByName(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You are looking for the `unionByName` function but with specfiying `allowMissingColumns=True` keyword.

This function is since `spark>=3.1` available. If you are using an older version consider the other answer from Martin Cook.

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

df3:

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data = [Row(name="John", age=27), Row(name="Tony", age=27)],
    schema=StructType([
        StructField(name="name", dataType=StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField(name="age", dataType=IntegerType(), nullable=True),
]))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data = [Row(name="John", zip=1234), Row(name="Tony", zip=1235)],
    schema=StructType([
        StructField(name="name", dataType=StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField(name="zip", dataType=IntegerType(), nullable=True)
]))

df3 = df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True)
df3.display()
```

Comment: in my version of spark allowMissingColumns is not recognised

Comment: what is your spark version?